# sem_wait is ignored in my program

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, shared-memory

I write a simple project on shared memory in linux. Two programs share memory, one is writing letters to it and second is reading them from it. I decided to use semaphores in order to ensure that no new letter is produced until it is read.

The problem is that my writer process is ignoring sem_wait( reading ) when its value is 0 and it should wait. It finishes its job before the reader even starts. I run it through `./writer & ./reader`.

I enclose the code. There are a few unused elements here because it is not the final version yet. However problem already arised.

```
/* writer.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    key_t shmkey = 0xF00;
    int bytes = sizeof(char)*3 + sizeof(sem_t) * 3;
    int shmid;
    char* sharedMemory;
    sem_t *writing, *reading, *working;

    if ( (shmid = shmget( shmkey, bytes, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666 )) < 0 )
    {
        shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
        shmctl( shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL );
        return 1;
    }
    if ( (sharedMemory = (char*) shmat( shmid, NULL, 0 )) == (char*) -1 )
    {
        shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
        shmctl( shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL );
        return 1;
    }

    writing = (sem_t*)(sharedMemory + 3);
    reading = writing + 1;
    working = reading + 1;

    sem_init( writing, 0, 0 );
    sem_init( reading, 0, 0 );

    sharedMemory[2] = 'w'; // writer is running
    char c;
    for( c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c )
    {
        *sharedMemory = c;
        sem_post( writing );
        sem_wait( reading );
    }
    sharedMemory[2] = 'q';
    while ( sharedMemory[2] != 'w' );
    sharedMemory[2] = 'q';
    shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
    shmctl( shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

And the reader,

```
/* reader.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    key_t shmkey = 0xF00;
    int bytes = sizeof(char)*3 + sizeof(sem_t) * 3;
    int shmid; 
    char* sharedMemory;
    sem_t *writing, *reading, *working;

    sleep(1); // wait until writer allocates fresh memory
    if ( (shmid = shmget( shmkey, bytes, 0666 )) < 0 )
    {
        shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
        return 1;
    }
    if ( (sharedMemory = (char*) shmat( shmid, NULL, 0 )) == (char*) -1 )
    {
        shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
        return 1;
    }

    if ( sharedMemory[2] != 'w' ) // is writer running?
    {
        shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
        return 1;
    }

    writing = (sem_t*)(sharedMemory + 3);
    reading = writing + 1;
    working = reading + 1;

    //sleep(5); //@REMOVE

    char c;
    do
    {
        sem_wait( writing );
        c = *sharedMemory;
        sem_post( reading );
        printf( "%c\n", c );
    } while ( sharedMemory[2] == 'w' ); 
    sharedMemory[2] = 'w';
    shmdt( (void*) sharedMemory );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The documentation says the second argument to `sem_init()` should be nonzero for the semaphore to be shared between processes - you would appear to be invoking undefined behaviour. What happens if you change that?

Comment: @Notlikethat it does not help

Comment: Also you should be checking the return values - on failure reading `errno` will tell you what was wrong.

Comment: @woolstar I didn't know that. I used semaphores before but without that procedure, without shared memory though. Could you give me a hint how the command should look like, i.e. what flags should I set and if destroy() is enough at the end of the code to free the it's memory?

Comment: Sorry, the style you are using is called unnamed semaphores which I was familiar with, but is essentially valid.

Comment: @woolstar so should I switch to named semaphores? I haven't worked with them before, I thought unnamed approach is suitable here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sharedMemory + 3` is not properly aligned for type `sem_t`. Since you don't know the alignment requirement for `sem_t`, you need to make sure that your `sem_t` objects start at an offset in the shared memory segment that is a multiple of `sizeof(sem_t)` (this works because the alignment requirement of any object evenly divides its size).

Note that you should be checking the return values of `sem_wait` and `sem_post`. Then you could inspect `errno` if they fail and that would give you information on why they're failing (however in your case I suspect the `errno` value may have been less than helpful).

Comment: I was checking them. They were equal to 0. so it seems sem_init() works.

Comment: I don't get why should I check errno. Writer process ends and returns 0 so there shouldn't be any errors from the program point of view, am I correct?

Comment: I changed `bytes = sizeof(sem_t)*4` which to my understanding creates the desired offset. It didn't help.

Comment: That's not the change I suggested. I said you should change the first 3 (the one multiplied by `sizeof(char)`, which incidentally is an ugly way of writing 1) and the 3 in `sharedMemory + 3`, both to `sizeof(sem_t)`.

Comment: As for checking for an error return and checking `errno`, it won't necessarily help find your error, because you're invoking undefined behavior. But in general, `sem_post` and `sem_wait` could fail (especially `sem_wait` can fail with `EINTR` when interrupted by a signal), so you should be checking their return values rather than assuming they succeeded. In your case, I suspect `sem_wait` is getting `EINVAL` or `EFAULT` or something from the kernel for passing an invalid (misaligned) address to wait on.

Comment: Thank you. You were right about the memory. But errno seemed to return junk in my case or I was doing something wrong.

Comment: In general, `errno` may contain junk. With most functions that use `errno`, you must first check the return value of the function to see that it failed (often -1 or a null pointer means failure; this is specific to the function, and documented) and only then access `errno`.